# WIndows Phone returning null object

Tags: windows-phone

M new  with windows mobile and trying to login using webservice managed in SOAP. After Completion  of method it returns an LoginResponse ob as result.

but if M trying to access it member using object its show error for all member .

Like if M trying for e.Result.Statuscode.toString() its generate error.

Can any one help on this

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into setting the POST data in the HTTP Post ? Try this http://geekswithblogs.net/rakker/archive/2006/04/21/76044.aspx